# Python Web Scraping - handling page 404 errors

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am performing web scraping in via Python \ Selenium \ Chrome headless driver which involves executing a loop:

```
# perform loop

CustId=2000
while (CustId<=3000):
  

  # Part 1: Customer REST call:
  urlg = f'https://mywebsite.com/customerRest/show/?id={CustId}'
  driver.get(urlg)

  soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"lxml")

  dict_from_json = json.loads(soup.find("body").text)

  #logic for webscraping is here......

  CustId = CustId+1

  # close driver at end of everything

driver.close()
```

However, sometime the page might not exist when the customer ID is certain number.  I have no control over this and the code stops with page not found 404 error.  How do I ignore this though and just move on with the loop?

I'm guessing I need a TRY....EXCEPT though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the page body `h1` tag what the text appeared when it comes `404 error` and then you can put that in if clause to check if not then go inside the block.

```
CustId=2000
while (CustId<=3000):
    urlg = f'https://mywebsite.com/customerRest/show/?id={CustId}'
    driver.get(urlg)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"lxml")
    if not "Page not found" in soup.find("body").text:     
      dict_from_json = json.loads(soup.find("body").text)
      #logic for webscraping is here......

    CustId=CustId+1
```

Or

```
CustId=2000
while (CustId<=3000):
    urlg = f'https://mywebsite.com/customerRest/show/?id={CustId}'
    driver.get(urlg)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"lxml")
    if not "404" in soup.find("body").text:     
      dict_from_json = json.loads(soup.find("body").text)
      #logic for webscraping is here......

    CustId=CustId+1
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a way to do this would be to try:

```
try:
    urlg = f'https://mywebsite.com/customerRest/show/?id={CustId}'
    driver.get(urlg)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"lxml")

    dict_from_json = json.loads(soup.find("body").text)

    #logic for webscraping is here......

    CustId = CustId+1
except:   
    print("404 error found, moving on")
    CustId = CustId+1
```

Sorry if this doesn't work, I havent tested it out.

Comment: If you are not sure that your answer is correct it would be better to skip it for the moment and come up with it again if you are pretty sure - In addition how could you be sure that there is an 404 error in your `try` block. Couldn't it be that something completely different is happening and you wouldn't even notice it without an explicit check?

Answer (score 0):

An ideal approach would be to use the [`range()`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_range.asp) function and `driver.quit()` at the end as follows:

```
for CustId in range(2000, 3000):
    try:
        urlg = f'https://mywebsite.com/customerRest/show/?id={str(CustId)}'
        driver.get(urlg)
        if not "404" in driver.page_source:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"lxml")
            dict_from_json = json.loads(soup.find("body").text)
            #logic for webscraping is here......
except:
        continue
driver.quit()
```